# I want to return array

Tags: javascript

This is my array

```
{ Colors: 'Blues',
  Department: 'Clearance',
  Size: [ 'Runners', 'Custom Sizes' ],
  Shape: 'Round',
  Designer: 'B. Smit',
 }
```

I want the output :

```
{ Colors: 'Blues',
  Department: 'Clearance',
  Size: 'Runners',
  Shape: 'Round',
  Designer: 'B. Smit',
 }
{ Colors: 'Blues',
  Department: 'Clearance',
  Size: 'Custom Sizes',
  Shape: 'Round',
  Designer: 'B. Smit',
 }
```

I tried this but not getting result

Comment: You tried *what* ?

Comment: That’s not an array. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sunnyn, try the below solution. sure it will help you.

```
  var obj = { Colors: 'Blues',
              Department: 'Clearance',
              Size: [ 'Runners', 'Custom Sizes' ],
              Shape: 'Round',
              Designer: 'B. Smit',
  };

var tmpArr = [];

for(var index in obj.Size) {
    var myCustObj = {};
     for (var k in obj){
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
             myCustObj[k] = obj[k];
          }
     }
     myCustObj.Size = obj.Size[index];
     tmpArr.push(myCustObj);
}

console.log(tmpArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do something like this

```
function convert(inp){
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< inp.Size.length; i++){
    result.push({
      Colors: inp.Colors,
      Department: inp.Department,
      Size: inp.Size[i],
      Shape: inp.Shape,
      Designer: inp.Designer
    });
  }
  return result;
}


convert({
  Colors: 'Blues',
  Department: 'Clearance',
  Size: [ 'Runners', 'Custom Sizes' ],
  Shape: 'Round',
  Designer: 'B. Smit',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 or modern browser...

```js
const input = {
    Colors: 'Blues',
    Department: 'Clearance',
    Size: [ 'Runners', 'Custom Sizes' ],
    Shape: 'Round',
    Designer: 'B. Smit'
};

const output = input.Size.map(size => (
    Object.assign(
        {},
        input,
        {
            Size: size
        }
    )
));

alert(JSON.stringify(output, null, '\t'));
```

Comment: I tried this :if (variants.Size.length>0) {
                var myArray = [];  
               sizeArray = variants.Size;
               length = sizeArray.length;
               for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
                    size = sizeArray[i];
                    variants.Size = size;
                    myArray.push(variants);
                }
           console.log("VarSizwe===========",myArray);
        }